# php, when number_format() meets date_diff()

Tags: php, number-formatting, dateinterval

my system: win 7 32bit, wampserver 2.1e
please help me find out the solution of following confusion.

```
<?php
echo number_format(10,2);   //output 10.00
$datetime1 = date_create('2012-12-13');
$datetime2 = date_create('2012-12-14');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%d');  //output 1 
echo number_format(10,2);   // output :.00
echo number_format(10,2);  //output 10.00 
?>
```

the first number_format() after dateinterval->format get a wrong result.
does number_format conflicts with dateinterval format?

Answer (score 0):

I have ran the same script under Win7 64bit WampServer 2.2 and I didn't see any conflicts.

Probably your confusion comes from the fact that you are printing the values without newlines.

Try this:

```
<?php
echo number_format(10,2)     . "<br>";
$datetime1 = date_create('2012-12-13');
$datetime2 = date_create('2012-12-14');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%d') . "<br>";
echo number_format(10,2)     . "<br>";
echo number_format(10,2)     . "<br>";
```

It prints:

```
10.00
1
10.00
10.00
```